# Need to fetch path of the directory selected through chooseFileSystemEntries

Tags: html5-filesystem, native-file-system-api-js

We are creating an offline player to minimize buffering with the FileSystem API. I am able to open a directory and fetch videos from there but I am still unable to fetch the path. I am looking to get access to the path of the directory the user-selected but I don't know how. The documentation isn't clear

```
window.onload = function() {
    butDir = document.getElementById('butDirectory');
    videoDiv = document.getElementById('videos');
    let fileHandle;
    butDir.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
        const opts = {type: 'openDirectory'};
        const handle = await window.chooseFileSystemEntries(opts);
        const entries = await handle.getEntries();
        for await (const entry of entries) {
            var file = entry.name;
        }    
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not yet supported by the API. In [browser-nativefs](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/browser-nativefs), we polyfill it using the legacy `webkitRelativePath` property. This is the relevant excerpt of the [code](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/browser-nativefs/blob/master/src/nativefs/directory-open.mjs#L26-L30).